# Local factoriality of moduli space of semistable G-Higgs bundles on curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be an irreducible smooth complex projective curve of genus $g \geq 2$. Let $G$ be a connected reductive affine algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathcal{M}_{G, Higgs}^{\delta}$ be the moduli space of semistable holomorphic principal $G$-Higgs bundles over $X$ of topological type $\delta \in \pi_1(G)$. Is it true that the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_{G, Higgs}^{\delta}$ is ***locally factorial***? If not in general, when this holds true? Can anyone give any reference for this?

Comment: I am not familiar with moduli spaces of $G$-Higgs bundles, but  there is a general theorem about local factoriality.  By Grothendieck's proof of Samuel's conjecture (SGA 2), every locally finite type $k$-scheme that is locally complete intersection and whose singular locus has codimension $\geq 4$ is locally factorial.  In particular, if there is a perfect obstruction theory and the space has pure dimension equal to the "expected" dimension, then the space is a local complete intersection.  So then the problem is to bound the dimension of the singular locus.